# How to estimate eps using knn distance plot in DBSCAN

Tags: python, image-processing, cluster-analysis, knn, dbscan

I have the following code to estimate the `eps` for DBSCAN. If the code is fine then I have obtained the `knn distance plot`. The code is :

```
ns = 4
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=ns).fit(data)
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(data)
distanceDec = sorted(distances[:,ns-1], reverse=True)
plt.plot(indices[:,0], distanceDec)
```

Where `data` is the array of pixel locations (rows and columns). I have obtained a plot but I am not getting how do I determine the `eps`. According to `DBSCAN` paper,

> the threshold point is the first point in the first valley of the
>   sorted k-dist graph

I dont know how do I implement it in the code. Moreover, is `ns = 4` is my `minPts` or is there any way to estimate `minPts` from `eps`?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
plt.plot(list(range(1,noOfPointsYouHave+1)), distanceDec)
```

You'll get an elbow plot. The distance where you have a sharp change in curve is your epsilon.

You can also make reverse=False, if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this is to be determined *visually* by a human.

Automation doesn't seem to work.

Or you can use OPTICS.

Comment: You probably are looking at the n-1 nearest neigh or, as I assume your code will always return 0 as first distance. Also, your choice of x for the plot doesn't make sense to me.